# Fading Array Elements In and Out Randomly From Database

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, mongodb, fade

I am working on a personal project where users submit a statement and it is added to a MongoDB collection. Assume this collection has a total of 50 statements. I would like these statements to fade in and out at random with there only being a maximum of 7 statements on the webpage at any given time.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem because ideally I'd want to make use of all the statements in the collection. I was thinking of creating an array and randomly selecting 7 statements to fill this array. That is as far as I've gotten because then what shall I do? Be in constant communication with my database to randomly replace elements in the array? Not sure if that can be done/is advisable. Or should I have the collection loaded into the page beforehand? Not sure if that's recommended either because what if we're talking about a collection with an extremely large amount of entries.

Or maybe both of my approaches are wrong. Hope someone can share an approach with some pseudocode perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sample": {
      "size": 7
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WCs7tYlMCBw)